# Swift Filemanager fails to create temporary directory

Tags: swift, nsfilemanager

This Code:

```
let csvString = self.generateCSV()
let tmpURL = try FileManager.default.url(for: .itemReplacementDirectory,
                                         in: .userDomainMask,
                                         appropriateFor: nil,
                                         create: true)
let tempFileUrl = tmpURL.appendingPathComponent("App-DigiAufklaerung-\(self.formatDateToPrecision(Date())).csv")
let data = csvString.data(using: .utf8)
try data?.write(to: tempFileUrl,
                options: .atomic)
self.csvFile = tempFileUrl
```

(I thought) should create a tmp file, from which i can then share the cdv through AirDrop, but the creation of the tmpDir fails, what am i doing wrong here?

This error message was printed several times:

```
CFURLSetTemporaryResourcePropertyForKey failed because it was passed an URL which has no scheme
```

Comment: It failed at the first try, a had a strategically placed print after it, that was never reached :)

Comment: There error suggests that URL is missing the scheme, which would be "file:" at the start.  Have you tried printing it so you can see what the URL actually is?

Comment: is this iOS or MacOS? I believe that on iOS things are not so easy. First of all, on iOS you cannot simply create a temporary folder in `user domain`.

Comment: From the documentation of `url(for:in:appropriateFor:create:)`: "You can use this method to create a new temporary directory. To do so, specify FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.itemReplacementDirectory for the directory parameter, userDomainMask for the domain parameter, and a URL for the url parameter which determines the volume of the returned URL.". Have you tried this?

Comment: I did it using `NSTemporaryDirectory()`